# Fade out ellement WHILE scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, fade

I've found a lot if info about fading an element out or in when the page is scrolls to a certain point, but I'd like to know if it's possible to have a fixed element fade out only if the page is being scrolled and fade in if not.

Any help finding some info about this would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Seems a little redundant. When a user scrolls using the scroll wheel the scroll event occurs for all of less than one second.

Comment: To answer your question, yes, its possible. Just about anything is possible. Worthwhile? Maybe not. Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: It's a fixed menu at the bottom of a page that is set up with a parallax effect, so it scrolls from frame to frame when a button is triggered. While the page is scrolling to the next frame, I don't want to see the menu items. I haven't tried anything yet, as I haven't come across anything that looks like it will work - still learning js, so I'm reliant on tutorials and such. thanks!